# Time complexity of a function that i dont think could even exist

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

So i got this question in the exam,
Find the time complexity of the function

```
logn+3nlogn-100n^2+50
```

All logs have base 2

Can anyone tell if the answer is `nlogn` or `n^2` even though I doubt such a function could even exist for an algorithm.

Comment: n^2 should be the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that such complexity function would never exist since after a certain value of n, your function is always negative(due to -100n^2), which is not possible. Still if someone asks you the complexity of such a function it should be answered to be O(n^2).